# How can I test my internet connection's stability and detect very short sub-second outages?

Tags: networking, internet, isp, diagnostic, cable-modem

I'm experiencing a problem with my cable internet connection where it will occasionally drop out for less than a second. It's barely noticeable most of the time, but when downloading large files, using video conferencing, or connected to VPN it can be a real annoyance.

At this stage I'm not sure where the fault lies, so I'm planning on connecting my laptop directly to my cable modem and running a multi-hour test to see if the drops still happen, since then I can eliminate my router and everything behind it as being the source of the issue.

I'm not sure what I can use to test for that, however. I need something that will notice when the connection drops for a split second.

What sorts of tools or techniques can I use for such a thing?

Comment: You could pipe the output from continual ping to file. However, what application is not fault tolerant? Downloading should continue after a missed block, video might glitch for a second, but is that an issue?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I've tried using pings, but it doesn't consistently catch the problem. The problem applications have been Skype and just downloading files via a web browser. It gets much worse when my system is set to automatically connect to my VPN, as every time it loses a connection it takes several seconds for the VPN to reconnect, during which time I have no internet connectivity at all.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart My provider is Comcast.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things to check with a docsis modem.

Open a browser and go to **192.168.100.1**, the last time I laid hands on a Comcast modem there was no user/pass to log into the modem diagnostics.

Go to the diagnostic section, check the signal to noise ratios, this will let you know if you have a borderline failing signal strength. Mid 30's for downstream is acceptable, 45+ on the upstream is about the upper limit before the modem starts creating noise.

After that, check the log section for any "T" based errors, look for **critical** and **severe**. The T-based errors are at the street level. A call to Comcast telling them you found these errors will create a dispatch ticket and get it resolved.

If you found that the SNR levels were unacceptable, you can disconnect the splitters in the house going to the T.V's make a straight connection from the aerial/underground cable coming to the house directly to the modem. Check the SNR levels again, if the are now acceptable, you have a problem with either the splitter or inside wiring. If the signal doesn't clean up when you do this, you most likely have a problem with either the feeder cable (aerial/underground) coming to the house or something is wrong at the street level.

You can also setup iperf/jperf to do a long running test. It's a server/client program, so you would have to setup the server side at a friend's house etc. My guess is that anything that would cause these hiccups would be in the log.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the tips! My cable modem is relatively new and isn't leased from Comcast so some of the info you're talking about isn't readily available. But from what I see, the SNR levels for downstream are all between 40.2 dB to 40.8 dB. For upstream it doesn't provide any SNR data but it does list "power" which is between 44.5 dBmV and 46 dBmV. The system log has no recent errors. My cable line is not split between a cable box and the modem -- only the modem is connected. I'd be curious if you have any comments about that. I do wonder if this modem is defective.

Comment: It could be, but when I was working for Comcast out of high school we had to replace the feeder if our meter read the signal levels you have. Double check the incoming line, make absolutely sure that you have a straight connection to the modem i.e double female barrel style adapter, and not what's known as a "trap". If you can, plug the modem in with a laptop right where it comes in. If the SNR values are good like this, you know you have an inside wiring problem. If not, call Comcast, it is their responsibility to get proper signal to the dmarc.